# Do we receive notifications about new answers posted for a question on which I started bounty?

Tags: support, bounties, notifications

I started a bounty on a question. After I started the bounty, some answers were posted and I received notifications about these answers.

[image]

P.S. I didn't follow the bounty question.

Is receiving notifications like these common? I don't recall receiving notifications like these in the past.

Comment: TL;DR: yes. From the faq: "Another user answers one of your questions, **or a question on which you have an active bounty**."

Comment: @ShadowTheGPTWizard Thanks! Shouldn't this be mentioned in the bounty FAQ https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/?

Comment: Well it won't hurt, need to add another bullet item in the faq question, then another section in the answer.